# Passing no parameters to a function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

```
const range = (...myData: number[]) => {
  myData.sort();
  return myData[myData.length-1] - myData[0];
}
```

Codecademy says "Although the type for the rest parameter is an array of numbers, calling range() with no argument is perfectly valid and generates no TypeScript error. However, a value of NaN will be returned."

I thought TypeScript gives an error if we don’t provide a value for the arguments of a function, unless they have a `?` after their name.

Comment: `...myData: number[]` means zero or more numbers, each as separate parameters, not 1 or more. Are you looking for ways to change the type to force there to be at least 1 number? or are you looking to modify the code to return something other than `NaN` when given zero?

Comment: A rest parameter is an array of the remaining parameters that weren't previously defined in the function. They can be empty (i.e. no arguments at the point of the parameter, e.g. `range()`, in which case `myData: number[] = [] -> myData.length === 0`), or they can contain values (i.e. one of more arguments at the point of the parameter, e.g. `range(1, 2, 3)`, in which case `myData: number[] = [1, 2, 3] -> myData.length === 3`). The reason `range()` returns `NaN` is because: `myData[-1] - myData[0] -> undefined - undefined === NaN`

Answer (score 2):

The rest parameter is special. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) how it works in plain JS. Arguments given as rest parameters are put into a JS Array. If you omit the arguments then an empty array is given as the rest parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should expect at least one argument, because `undefined - undefined = NaN`

```js
const range = <N extends number, Data extends N[]>(...myData:[N,...Data]) => {
  myData.sort();
  return myData[myData.length-1] - myData[0];
}

range() // error
range(2) // ok
range(2,3) // ok
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html) you can find some docs
If you want to be super safe, turn on all strict flags in your tsconfig.
In this case, you can consider [`noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess) flag